# how to enable port 7777

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, tcp, udp

I am initiating file transfer using tcp on openfire server. But I am not able to open the port number 7777, from which I need to send files. I changed the security setting in the admin console panel of the aws. But still when I tried to send the files I am getting the error.

I tried to change the custom TCP rules, by opening only the 7777 port. But still I am not able to resolve it. Kindly help.

linux ubuntu

Comment: Is your FTP server actually listening on 7777?

Comment: @Chopper: How do I test it???

Comment: Well did you specifically change your ftp server config to listen on 7777? they dont just listen to every port for the hell of it - in fact port 7777 is usually used by a piece of malware/virus, certainly isn't a recommended port of ftp traffic.

Comment: A quick test would be `netstat -an|grep 7777`, which doesn't need privilege to run.  Let us know the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your AMI has a firewall enabled that is blocking port 7777. Ubuntu usually uses [**ufw**](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/serverguide/C/firewall.html) to control it's firewall.

run

```
sudo ufw status
```

If it reports

```
Status: inactive
```

then your problem lies elsewhere.

If it reports

```
Status: active
```

followed by a list of rules then you probably need to add a rule to allow access on port 7777

```
sudo ufw allow 7777
```

Comment: @lain: it was inactive first then I enabled it i got the msg saying"Rules updated" but I tried sudo ufw allow 777 but still the status is inactive, what will be the problem I have updated the security group to accept all TCP and UDP rules

Comment: @JeevanDongre: If the firewall was inactive (like I said) your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: @lian: let me brief u about the application which I am developing I have installed open fire xmpp chat server in the server and I am trying to initiate the p2p, that means sending files from one mobile to another mobile via port 7777, which is a default port in openfire server, but I am not able to open that particular port. Thanks a lot for guiding me :)